# Searching for a folder and a specific file in a hidden folder in Delphi

Tags: delphi, search

so essentially I'm trying to write a script using Delphi that finds the location of a file (*main.db*) in the `Users/[user]/AppData/Roaming/Skype/[Username]/` directory, the problem is thus -

I don't know what the [user] is in advance, nor what [Username] is, and I'm unsure if I can wildcard this. I'd prefer it to be in console app form so that I can adapt it for what I need, as well.

This is what I currently have:

```
program SearchConsole2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

procedure FindFilePattern(root:String;pattern:String);
var
  SR:TSearchRec;
begin
  root:=IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(root);
  if FindFirst(root+'*.*',faAnyFile,SR) = 0 then
  begin
      repeat
          if ((SR.Attr and faDirectory) = SR.Attr ) and (pos('.',SR.Name)=0) then
             FindFilePattern(root+SR.Name,pattern)
          else
          begin
           if pos(pattern,SR.Name)>0 then Writeln(Root+SR.Name);
          end;
      until FindNext(SR)<>0;
  end;
end;

begin
  FindFilePattern('C:\users\','.db');
  readln;
end.
```

// I'm not sure what I'm missing here, `C:\Users\` searching for .exe is able to pull out things from inside the [User] folder - But I really need a way of extracting the name of the [User] folder and the skype[Username] folder, or failing that, using a wildcard for both, if at all possible?

Comment: To get directly to the Application Data roaming folder you can use the `SHGetKnownFolderPath` function with [`FOLDERID_RoamingAppData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx#FOLDERID_RoamingAppData) folder ID on Vista above, or `SHGetFolderPath` with [`CSIDL_APPDATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494(v=vs.85).aspx#CSIDL_APPDATA) folder ID on Windows 2k up to Windows XP. The rest of the path, the `[Username]`, isn't that a Skype username or something related to Skype ?

Comment: Yes. Absolutely do not hard code `Users/.../AppData/Roaming` since that may vary. Beyond that it is simple.

Comment: Yeah, [Username] will be the skype username, obviously I don't know that in advance, so it needs to be either ignored and searched past or wildcarded, I guess? 

It's been a long time since I scripted anything, how do I add           FOLDERID_RoamingAppData into the code I've got above, or if I can't, is there a specific way I should go about using it?

Comment: Start by reading the documentation that TLama linked to

Comment: So.. Would I use something like: 
`type`
  `KNOWNFOLDERID = TGuid;`

`function SHGetKnownFolderPath(
  const rfid: KNOWNFOLDERID;
  dwFlags: DWORD;
  hToken: THandle;
  out ppszPath: PWideChar
): HResult; stdcall; external 'Shell32.dll';`

- I saw this was commented on a previous question WRT Delphi 7, which is what I'm using - If so, what do I need to call in order to use this (it doesn't seem to work on it's own!) - Sorry to ask so many questions, It's been a long time since I programmed anything, especially in Delphi.

Comment: Personally I'd call `SHGetSpecialFolderPath` from the `ShlObj` unit passing `CSIDL_APPDATA`.

Comment: Okay, Thanks. What other parameters do I pass through? I get a message telling to pass (hwndOWNER: HWND, IpszPath:PAnsiChar, nFolder: Integer, FCreate: LongBool) - What should these values be? (I've not encountered them before!

Comment: Tom, your last comment doesn't look like one that would be posted by someone who had read the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply(?). I think you grossly overestimate how much I understand about what I'm doing! I read the documentation, but in all honesty I don't know what it means. It's been a long, long time since I did anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

Make a call to [GetEnvironmentVariable](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Method.asp?NameSpace=System&Class=Environment&Type=Class&Method=GetEnvironmentVariable)(), like this:

```
GetEnvironmentVariable('APPDATA')
```

This will return to you the path to *Roaming folder* without needing to hard-code the username.